# JS Cookie Plugin + If Statement Not Working

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to use the JS Cookie Plugin to read the value of a cookie and include a notification bar (Hello Bar) if the value is not 1.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- HelloBar code start -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.hellobar.com/hellobar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if($.cookie('returning_user') !== '1') {
    new HelloBar(12345,12345);
}
</script>
<!-- HelloBar code end -->
```

1. Is !== the right operator to test for inequality here?
2. By putting 1 in quotes, am I testing for a string when I really want an integer?

Right now, the interior part of the code (new HelloBar ...) is never executed.

Comment: I just meant "Is the test I wrote (!== '1') going to test that the cookie's value is not equal to one. Or, should it be != or !===, etc.

Comment: `1.` Yes `!==` and `===` are the right operators to use almost always in _JavaScript_. `2.` You are testing for a _String_, but this is not necessarily wrong - cookies are _Strings_. To debug this, you need to check the value of `$.cookie('returning_user')`, e.g. using `console.log`

Comment: @PaulS. Cookies are strings, but the jQuery cookie plugin might uses JSON encoding to store non-strings in cookies.

Comment: @Barmar looked it up, [jquery-cookie on github](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), looks like it does have a _JSON_ option. I think it must be off by default though, because it would confuse people who expected normal cookies to read server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!==` will check the Type and value Both

so if you want to match Integer

than use

`if($.cookie('returning_user') !== 1) {`

`===` and `!==` are strict comparison operators:

> JavaScript has both strict and
>   type-converting equality comparison.
>   For strict equality the objects being
>   compared must have the same type and:
>
> - Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of
>     characters, same length, and same
>     characters in corresponding positions.
> - Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have
>     the same number value). NaN is not
>     equal to anything, including NaN.
>     Positive and negative zeros are equal
>     to one another.
> - Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or
>     both are false.
> - Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object.
> - Null and Undefined types are == (but not ===). [I.e. Null==Undefined (but not Null===Undefined)]

[Comparison Operators - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

```
0==false   // true
0===false  // false, because they are of a different type
1=="1"     // true, auto type coercion
1==="1"    // false, because they are of a different type
```